# Why doesn't Zaeed show up (for me) in ME: 3 if he survived and was loyal?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am playing Mass Effect 3 on Xbox 360 and I've made it to the Citadel: Volus Ambassador mission.

I know Zaeed is supposed to show up during during this mission but I've had several playthroughs and he's never shown up.

Is this a glitch or something?  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you still have the ME2 DLC installed that introduced him? I'm not sure if it's required but it would be worth testing.

Comment: I think this depends on the save file you used for the ME2 import. I had Katsumi die because I imported a save file where I was mid way through her loyalty mission on ME2!

Comment: Probably not related, but here's another place Zaeed won't show up.  This time, he *didn't* survive:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100293/errors-on-the-memorial-wall

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to have his DLC for ME2, have him loyal and returning alive (and import that save, of course)

> In Mass Effect 3, Liara's data terminal indicates several purchases Zaeed made in preparation for war. Among these were a weapon repair kit and parts for a discontinued Avenger rifle series. This suggests that Zaeed wanted to go on one final mission with his beloved rifle, Jessie.

As stated on the [wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Zaeed_Massani#Mass_Effect_3) (spoilers!):

**During Korlack's mission**:

Zaheed dead after ME2:

> If you did not have him alive after ME2, you won't see Zaheed when opening Din's door, but two mercenaries instead.

Zaheed alive and loyal after ME2:

> If he survives, the Commander can speak with him  before the final battle.

Zaheed alive but not loyal:

> If Zaeed wasn't loyal to the mission, he will die saving Korlack. Oddly enough, he won't appear on the memorial wall on the Normandy's crew deck.