# Errors on the Memorial Wall?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In previous Mass Effect games, I lost a few good people.  So I was pleasantly surprised to find that a Memorial Wall was erected on the Normandy SR-2 in Mass Effect 3, honoring those who'd fallen in battle.

However, there's one name missing.  Zaeed Massani.  He did not survive the suicide mission in the game I imported from Mass Effect 2.  Several other memorable crew members lost are on the wall, as well as (according to [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Normandy_SR-2#Deck_3:_Crew_Deck)) 20 crew members lost with the demise of Normandy SR-1.

Also, presuming the Mass Effect Wiki data is correct, it seems the casualty count on my wall is just a bit further off.  From memory, I've lost...

Mass Effect 1:
- Richard L. Jenkins
- Ashley Williams

Mass Effect 2:
- Kasumi Goto
- Zaeed Massani
- Mordin Solus

Add that to the 20 names from the demise of SR-1 and I *should* have 25.  Interestingly, I *do* have 25.  But, as I've mentioned, Zaeed is nowhere to be found in the list, so the number should be 24.  Is there a known explanation for this?

Here's the people currently listed on my wall:

> Abishek Pakti
>   Alexei Dubyansky
>   Ashley Williams
>   Caroline Grenado
>   Germeen Barret
>   Hector Emerson
>   Jamin Bakari
>   Mandira Rahman
>   Monica Negulesco
>   Orden Laflamme
>   Richard L Jenkins
>   Rosamlind Dravin
>   Talitha Draven
>   Addison Chase
>   Amina Waaberi
>   Carlton Tucks
>   Charles Pressly
>   Harvy J Gladstone
>   Helen M Lowe
>   Kasumi Goto
>   Marcus Grieco
>   Mordin Solus
>   Raymond Tanaka
>   Robert Felawa
>   Silas Crosby

Comment: ...Wow, did you set out to get as many people as possible killed or something? :)

Comment: @Shadur Dunno why you ask.  The two from Mass Effect 1 were unavoidable, and it's hard to avoid at least one or two in Mass Effect 2 without following a walkthrough - which I obviously did not.  The destruction of Normandy SR-1 is another unavoidable loss, resulting in 20 deaths.

Comment: how could you possibly let Mordin die? :(

Comment: Actually, you don't need to follow a walkthrough; all the clues you need to decide who to assign to what kind of mission are right in the various conversations -- even if sometimes the hints are subtle, like Zaeed's stories very often involving being the only person that made it out alive indicating that he's a bad choice for squad leader.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ME2 assignment](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Normandy_Crash_Site_%28assignment%29), your list of casualties excluding the destroyed SR-1's staff, is as follows:

- Ashley Williams
- Richard L Jenkins
- Kasumi Goto
- Mordin Solus

Now we deduct the known deaths of Williams, Goto and Solus, and Jenkins. Hmm ... Kinda leaves *noone*.

This means: There are indeed - as proper counting of the casualty list of the SR-1 tells - **21** deaths counted for the destroyed Normandy SR-1. This is based on the fact that [Navigator Charles Pressly](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Pressly) does not have an associated dog tag on the crash site, but rather his data panel.

He is still counted among those fallen during the Collector attack, and is added to the list as he is a key figure of memorial regarding the loss of the SR-1, but he is not among the 20 unaccounted crewmen (lore-wise, this is mostly because Shepard themselves witnessed Pressly's death on the Normandy).

**As for why Zaeed doesn't show up** ... That's a (link may contain spoilers) [bug](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Zaeed_Massani#Mass_Effect_3), that might be explained lore-wise as ["Mercenaries that fight for their next paycheck aren't remembered in any war."](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/323/index/10395175) - Zaeed was only hired as a mercenary back in ME2.